# how to form select query by range

Tags: php, mysql, variables, range

hello i have a search engine for my site. i have two selection fields. i would like to give an example:

input_a: 3
input_b: 5

so the queries should look like:

```
if ( ($input_a == true) && ($input_b == false) ){
        $filter_orders[] = " `col` LIKE '%$input_a%' ";
    } 
    if ( ($input_a == false) && ($input_b == true) ){
        $filter_orders[] = " `col` LIKE '%$input_b%' ";
    } 
    if ( ($input_a == true) && ($input_b == true) ){
        $filter_orders[] = " `col`= `col`>='%$input_a%' AND `col` = `col`<='%$input_b%' ";
```

now the problem is, that i dont know, if the last query is incorrect or not. the logic behind that will be that in case of my example the range between 3 and 5 should be found.

so 1,2 `[3,4,5]` 6,7,8...

if there is someone who could help me out i really would appreciate.

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NO,** sadly that is everything but correct. It should be something like this.

```
$filter_orders[] = " `col`>='%$input_a%' AND `col`<='%$input_b%' ";
```

Comment: seems like that %xyz% only works in combination with LIKE. so i had to leave these and it works. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

That should be

```
$filter_orders[] = " `col`>='%$input_a%' AND `col`<='%$input_b%' ";
```

EDIT: 
You probably want the entire statement to look like this:

```
if ( (!empty($input_a) && is_int($input_a)) && (empty($input_b) || !is_int($input_b)) {
    $filter_orders[] = " `col`='%$input_a%' ";
} 
else if ( (empty($input_b) || !is_int($input_a)) && (!empty($input_b) && is_int($input_b)) ) {
    $filter_orders[] = " `col`='%$input_b%' ";
} 
else if ( !empty($input_a) && !empty($input_b) && is_int($input_a) && is_int($input_b) ) {
    $filter_orders[] = " `col`>='%$input_a%' AND `col`<='%$input_b%' ";
}
```

Inserting the `else if` instead of just `if` helps makes sure other `if`s arent executed if an earlier `if` is found toe be true.

Using the `=` instead of `LIKE` wille make sure that `3 == 3` and not `3 and 31 or 32`